# Не подключается ssh через public-key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Ubuntu 18.04x64 на обоих хостах

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@192.168.0.10

ssh -vvv user@192.168.0.10

debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey 
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey debug1: Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:0TxSX/JrA4MPDwj/iac86aOwmZbir+e6sGBp6CdiZK8 /home/alexandr/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug3: send_pubkey_test 
debug3: send packet: type 50 
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply 
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

user@user-desktop:~$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
UseDNS no
PermitRootLogin yes
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
AddressFamily any
Protocol 1, 2
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2 /etc/ssh/user/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server


ls -alh ~/.ssh
итого 24K
drwx------  2 user user 4,0K мая  3 15:35 .
drwxrwxrwx 28 user user 4,0K мая  3 16:24 ..
-rw-------  1 user user 2,5K мая  3 15:47 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 user user  771 мая  3 14:54 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  607 мая  3 14:54 id_dsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  444 мая  3 14:56 known_hosts
```

На сервере:

journalctl -f

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user/.ssh
```

Comment: Подключитесь на сервер пока что без public-key и покажите `ls -alh ~/.ssh`

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx` на домашнем каталоге не должно быть. Максимум `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: @AlexeyTen заменил на drwxr-xr-x 28 user user  4096 мая  3 16:24 user
 результат тот-же

Comment: Читайте логи серверного ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh

Решение найдено [здесь](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/8448160).